# How can one make sure that some specific directories are fully deleted (without any record of their deletion) from a USB/flash drive?

Tags: detection, usb-drive, timestamp

It seems data resides in USB somewhere until it's completely overwritten. But is there a way to delete big directories 10-100GB or so without zero-filling the remaining space and only eradicating those specific directories? Would the history of deleting those is eraseable too?

Can someone when recovering deleted data also know when the file was deleted (not when it was last written but deleted)?

Answer (score 1):

Not really - it's the same problem as with SSDs, in that the way flash memory works in both USB drives and SSDs involves a certain amount of overcapacity and the ability to mark certain areas as unusable. There is always a risk that data remains in a currently unusable area of the device, but which could be recovered by specialist tools.

Best option is usually to encrypt the whole drive before putting any sensitive data onto it, then only encrypted data will be left on any currently inaccessible sectors, which, without the rest of the data and the key (assuming a sensible cipher mode), should be impossible to turn back into useful data. If you already have sensitive data on the device which you need to be completely unrecoverable, only real option is physical destruction.

Comment: Can someone when recovering deleted data also know when the file was deleted (not when it was last written but deleted)?

Comment: Only if the metadata is recovered. The raw data has no concept of when it was created, modified or deleted - these are all stored elsewhere.

Comment: can the metadata also be recovered for something that was deleted in a normal fashion and then from recycle bin (after deleting file from USB it still shows in computer's recycle bin from where it is then deleted)?